# Getting the DIFFERENT position of an elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table and each row has a menu button. These buttons share the same class. I want to get the X , Y positions of the button I click. My current attempt is using the following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".actionMenu").click(function () {
        let element = this.className;
        let elementPos = $("." + element).position();
    })
})
```

My problem is that this will return the FIRST item with the matching class name. Is there a way that I can get the position of the element clicked without specifying a class?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upenrao/HEDvf/7/light/)

**ANSWER**

I was checking the position using the alert/console log and it was giving me the same answer each time, I tested it using an actual DIV and just changed the css and it works perfectly as intended, the div moves to the appropriate position, instead of position I used offset.

Thank you for all those who helped.

Comment: `this` is the element clicked.  `$(this)` will make a jQuery object with that element as the only element in the result stack.  There is no reason to try to look the element up.  You already have a reference.

Comment: `$(".actionMenu").on("click",function () { const elementPos = $(this).position(); ... })`

Comment: I did try using that, but I am getting the same position in return, I'll re-write the table in a fiddle and test it there to be sure it's not being broken by somewhere else.

Comment: Click edit, then the button marked `[<>]`  no need to use jsfiddle

Comment: Added the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/upenrao/HEDvf/7/light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do like this

```
$('.actionMenu').on('click', function () {
  let x_pos = $(this).position().top;
  let y_pos = $(this).position().left;
  alert("Top:"+x_pos+" Left:"+y_pos);
});
```

LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/wep142Lg/2/

```js
// From http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/jquery

// Change tab class and display content
$('.actionMenu').on('click', function() {
  console.log("Top:" + $(this).position().top + " Left:" + $(this).position().left);
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="actionMenu">Button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>
      <button class="actionMenu">Button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>
      <button class="actionMenu">Button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>
      <button class="actionMenu">Button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that `$(this).position()` could/should be cached and not repeated.

Comment: I tried this but I still got the same positions, even using your fiddle I get the two same positions. As Taplar said it seems that's being cached, I tried wiping it so as to start a "fresh" cache each time it's clicked but I didn't manage to do so.

I added a fiddle of what I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/upenrao/HEDvf/7/light/

Comment: It works now, I skipped the checking for the cords and just assigned them to the div in question and it moves perfectly.